# shortcuts for showing that $(x_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^n$ are uniformly equivalent to $\ell_p^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $1\leq p\leq\infty$.  For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we denote by $(e_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^n$ the canonical basis for $\ell_p^n$, and fix some other basis $(x_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^n$ for a given $n$-dimensional Banach space $X_n$.  Assume that each $(x_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^n$ is $K$-unconditional for some fixed $K\in[1,\infty)$.

**Goal.**  We want to show that $(x_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^\infty$ are uniformly equivalent to $(e_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^n$.  More precisely, we want to find $C\in[1,\infty)$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and every scalar sequence $(a_k)_{k=1}^n$,
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\frac{1}{C}\|\sum_{k=1}^na_ke_k^{(n)}\|_{\ell_p^n}\leq\|\sum_{k=1}^na_kx_k^{(n)}\|_{X_n}\leq C\|\sum_{k=1}^na_ke_k^{(n)}\|_{\ell_p^n}.\end{equation}

**Question.** Are there any easy (or relatively easy) shortcuts for achieving the above goal?

**Discussion.**  Obviously we may assume $a_k\geq 0$.

In case $p=1$, the right-hand estimate in $(1)$ follows from the triangle inequality so that we only need to show the left-hand estimate.

The case $p=\infty$ is even easier as we always get the left-hand inequality in $(1)$ by the weakness of the $\infty$-norm, and, thanks to uniform unconditionality, the right-hand inequality in $(1)$ follows as long as $\|x_1^{(n)}+\cdots+x_n^{(n)}\|_{X_n}\leq M$ for some $M\in[1,\infty)$ chosen independently of $n$.  (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856235/if-e-1e-2-cdotse-n-leq-c-for-all-n-then-e-i-i-1n-is-uniformly) for a short explanation of this.)

However, I don't see any easy methods for the cases $1<p<\infty$.  Am I out of luck?  What if, say, each $(x_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^n$ was uniformly equivalent to all its permutations? Or is there some other property which could make it easier?

Thanks guys!

Comment: I doubt that you can find a handy criterion for $p\in (1,\infty)$. The fact that we have such criteria for $p=1,\infty$ follows from the fact that these two bases are extreme cases in the class of *all* bases. Of course, your question is equivalent to complementation of the ultraproduct of $[x_k\colon k=1,\ldots, n]$ in some isomorphic copy of some space $L_p(\mu)$.

Comment: @TomekKania that's very interesting. In the specific case I am looking at, for each $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$ we have a normalized unconditional basis $(f_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ for a Banach space $F_{p,q}$, and I conjecture that it is equivalent to the $(\oplus_{n=1}^\infty\ell_q^{2^{n-1}})_{\ell_p}$ basis. The first step towards proving this conjecture is to show that each piece $(f_k)_{k=2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1}$ is uniformly equivalent to $\ell_q^{2^{n-1}}$. I have already proved the case $q=\infty$ but the case $q<\infty$ is likely to be more troublesome. Maybe an ultraproduct strategy could be helpful...?

Comment: More specifically, I am looking at the Tandori sequence space $tand(p)$ defined as those $(a_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ with finite norm $\|(\|(a_j)_{j\geq k}\|_\infty)_{k=1}^\infty\|_p$. (These are isomorphic preduals of Cesaro sequence spaces.) In a recent paper was shown $tand(1)\approx(\oplus\ell_\infty^{2^{n-1}})_1$. Using similar methods I showed $tand(p)\approx(\oplus\ell_\infty^{2^{n-1}})_p$ for $p\geq 1$. Now I conjecture that if we define $tand(p,q)$ as those sequences with finite norm $\|(\|(a_j)_{j\geq k}\|_q)_{k=1}^\infty\|_p$ then $tand(p,q)\approx(\oplus\ell_q^{2^{n-1}})_p$.

Comment: For $p,q$ in the reflexive range I also doubt that ultraproducts will be of help (they are useful if you want to disprove something; for example that the $c_0$-sum of $\ell_2^n$s is not isomorphic to $c_0$, but the other way around is tricky).